# How to filter Date format "2016-09-12 11:21:50 BRT" to format dd/MM/yyyy on Datatable or Angular Controller?

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, datatable, locale

I need convert a date from back-end (JAVA) to front-end (Angular), the format date is "2016-09-12 11:21:50 BRT" or "2016-09-12 11:21:50 BRST". I using a datatable javascript to populate a table on front-end. I need a filter for datatable or angular controller, I try used $filter of Angular, but did not work. Follow my code, I need parse **createDate** and **modifyDate** .

```
function loadTable(documents) {
    $("#dtDocs").DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: documents,
        autoWidth: false,
        searching: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        language: {
            "url": "/plugins/datatables/language/Portuguese-Brasil.json",
            "emptyTable": "Nenhum documento encontrado.",
            "search": "Buscar"
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'number' },
            { data: 'revision' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'class' },
            { data: 'fileName' },
            { data: 'createDate' },
            { data: 'modifyDate' },
            { data: function (row) {
                if (row.fileName.indexOf(".PDF") == -1 && row.fileName.indexOf(".pdf") == -1) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    return '<a href="' + row.download + '" target="_blank" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></a>';
                }
            }}

        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        processing: false,
        lengthChange: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Send properly ISO formatted dates from server or use a library like moment.js to parse irregular formats like yours

Comment: I resolve temporary this problem making the date transformation on the back end,  I now this library moment.js, but I would like to do it on front end using only angular or datatable.

Comment: Then you need to parse the date string. Current structure is not valid ISO format to pass to javascript Date which is what angular has to use